# return a variable from a map.on('singleclick') function OL3

Tags: openlayers

I want to return the variable 'myiframe' to use it in a Ext panel.
here is my code :

```
var myiframe;
  map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
  var viewResolution = /** @type {number} **/ (view.getResolution());
  var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
      {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
  if (url) {
    myiframe =
        "'"+'<iframe width="1400px" src='+'"' + url+ '"'+ '></iframe>'+"'";

  }
  return myiframe;
});
console.log(myiframe);
```

'myiframe' is always undefined, I don't know what is wrong in my code.